# Mesos marathon cannot destroy job

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

I have a dcos cluster that is running a website. The website runs on 20 docker instances. When I'm looking at my application I see that I have 24 instances. Where 2 instances have status started but **health unknown** and 2 have status **staged**. The old instance where from a previous deploy
I tried the follow things:

- destroy the application (result: Error destroying /azure-tracking-api: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds])
- kill all instances (result: they all restart )

In the log I don't see any major errors  except

*Cannot kill task azure-tracking-api.908a6c3e-8948-11e6-be5a-7e591cfeda59 of framework 517c75b9-0a13-4b3b-a29d-8d754239991b-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-93d96b66-c66e-4d28-b56e-8b2b2b959bf8@172.16.0.7:42546 because it is unknown; performing reconciliation*

The version that I use is 0.28.1

My question is can I fix this with a couple of commands. The only way that I know how to fix this is to setup a new cluster.

Comment: This looks to me like something we can ideally solve interactively since there are a couple of things to check. I see that you already have an account on the DC/OS Community Slack (dcos-community.slack.com) so if you want to we try to resolve it there, just ping me (mh9.mesosphere).

Comment: Hi Michael I will try to contact you in the net couple of days. I'm currently on a conference so wifi is not great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Marathon version you're using (1.1.2) has known [issues](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/4039) with lost tasks. Once DC/OS 1.8 is available on Azure the best option is to upgrade. As a workaround, for now, you can manually delete a task using Marathon's [HTTP API](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/generated/api.html#v2_apps__app_id__tasks__task_id__delete):

```
$ curl -X DELETE $MARATHON_URL/v2/apps/azure-tracking-api/tasks/$TASKID?force=true
```

Comment: Now DC/OS 1.8 is available via the Azure Marketplace, suggest to upgrade, see https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/administration/installing/cloud/azure/